# QPushbutton background image from 3 images

Tags: css, qt

I have three background images for a button - left.png, center.png and right.png. The left and right ones have rounded edges and the center one is a single line which need to extend based on the size of the button. How do I create such a button? I have considered the option of constructing the image on the fly and apply it to the button in the resize event, but am looking to see if this is possible through stylesheets. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you can't do it with using stylesheets. There you would be able to set just one picture as background. You can do this for example using QPainter and paintEvent. It's quite easy.

Comment: @Blood Upvote from me. Yes, I decided to go with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do it with QPainter and constructing the image, but honestly for the complexity level and for a button class you might be better off learning how to do it by constructing a paintEvent in full using the standard primitives. It'll give you better fine grain control, just involves a bit of leg work.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to just create the button in the paint event

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with background-image alone. But it may be done with the help of `border-image`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image

Use `background-repeat: repeat-x` to fill the button and `border-image` to round out the edges.

Comment: Upvote from me. Thank you for the suggestion, but it does not exactly solve my problem.